# Read latest file with a filename contains string in python

Tags: python, readfile

Assume that I have a list of file like this:

- abc_name.txt
- def_name.txt
- ghj_name.txt
- abcdefghj.txt
- xyz.txt

I knew how to read latest file by using `max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getmtime)`, but it could be any last created file.

I want to read file that contains 'name' in its name and this file was last created (for example "def_name.txt").

How can I do that in python?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you run a `bash` command:

```
$ ch /tmp
$ touch abc_name.txt def_name.txt ghj_name.txt abcdefghj.txt xyz.txt
```

From Python you can use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) to both glob the directory where the files are and have fine control of what time element you are testing.

```
from pathlib import Path 

p=Path('/tmp')

max([fn for fn in p.glob('*.txt') if 'name' in str(fn)], key=lambda f: f.stat().st_mtime)

# /tmp/ghj_name.txt
```

You can also change your glob so only files with `name` in them are returned:

```
max([fn for fn in p.glob('*name*.txt')], key=lambda f: f.stat().st_mtime)

# same result
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of files that match a pattern using `os.glob(pattern)`, where pattern is a unix-style shell pattern.  In your case, it would be `'*name*'`.

Once you have this list, you can then use your `max` function to pick the most recent of them.

Documentation on `glob` can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/glob.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. You can use `max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getmtime)`. You will need a the list of files. To get the list of files,

do something like this:

```
max([file for file in list_of_files if 'name' in file], key=os.path.getmtime)
```

Comment: while this answer helps the OP to solve the problem, a better answer would be when you explain the code. It will help others coming to SO for answers.

Comment: you should add `key = ` before `os.path.getctime)`